How to move changes to new worktree?
I have uncommitted and staged changes in my main branch. I want to put those existing changes in a different worktree, so that my main branch/folder stays clean. How do I do that?
I've tried variations of git worktree add -b new-branch ../feature but it doesn't move my changes to the new worktree, just keeps them in the original main folder.
Edit for clarification: I'm in the middle of a large merge, and there are a dozen unresolved file conflicts. I want a way to pause my progress on the merge and get back to it when I can, but I can't stash unmerged files. In the past I've just added them all and committed them to a different branch, then fixed the conflicts in later commits, but then I'm not able to use merge tools to help me resolve the conflicts.

Just do git checkout -b  and all your changes will go to the new branch. Add the files and commit.

@SteelFeather That doesn't move them to a different worktree though, it seems?

Do you have both uncommitted and stashed changes? git worktree won't move uncommitted changes.

@poignantpinata - What do you mean by that its not moving to different worktree? Did you do git add and git commit after doing git checkout -b . Your old branch will remain as it is and new changes will go to the new branch.

@SteelFeather I don't want to add and commit the files, I want to leave them uncommitted, as if they were stashed. I updated my question with some more information on what I'm trying to do.

It's still unclear what you want to move to the worktree. Is it just the stashed changes? Or is it some of the unstaged partially merged changes?

Why not just create another worktree for the main branch? Although git worktree add does not allow to create another worktree for an checked-out branch, you can create as many as you want for the commit referenced by the branch like git worktree add /path/to/worktree refs/heads/main and it creates a worktree in detached HEAD. And then you can commit on the clean detached main or resolve the previous conflicts.

@Schwern I would like all of my local staged and unstaged changes to be moved to a different worktree. If by stashed changes you mean the Git stash, that's not what I'm asking to move.

@poignantpinata You also said you're in the middle of a merge with conflicts. Your unstaged changes have merge conflicts... Oh no, did you start a merge with unstaged charges? And now you want to extract just those unstaged changes and leave the conflicts? Show us your git status please and be clear about which changes you're looking to move.

Can you git checkout -b <newBranch> in your current work tree, and then create a new worktree for main branch? git worktree add <path> <main_branch> The new worktree will be clean and will have your main branch checked out. And your original worktree will have your merged changes and a branch new branch.


I have uncommitted and staged changes in my main branch. I want to put those existing changes in a different worktree, so that my main branch/folder stays clean.
I've tried variations of git worktree add -b new-branch ../feature but it doesn't move my changes to the new worktree, just keeps them in the original main folder.

The actual files are the "worktree". git worktree add will share your stash with other worktrees, that lives in the shared .git directory, but it will not share uncommitted changes because those are the worktrees. You get freshly checked out files.
If you wish to move uncommitted changes to a new worktree, stash them, then apply them in to your new worktree.

But you don't need a new worktree. The simplest thing to do is to put it in a new branch with the same worktree.
git checkout -b new_branch

Now you can add your uncommitted changes, apply your stashed changes, and commit them. When you're done you can switch back to main. It's ok to commit them as a Work In Progress (WIP) and revise the commit later with git commit --amend.
If you only want to commit some of the changes to the new branch, use git add -p to make partial commits.

Thank you for your response! I do need worktrees in this case; I'm in the middle of a large merge with some resolved files and a dozen unresolved ones, and I want a way to pause my progress on the merge and get back to it when I can. I can't stash unmerged files, so is there another way to do that?

@poignantpinata Simplest thing is probably to just copy the files to the new worktree and git add -p the pieces you want. We need more information to suggest anything more sophisticated, see my comment on the question.

Can you git checkout -b <newBranch> in your current work tree, and then create a new worktree for main branch?  git worktree add <path> <main_branch> The new worktree will be clean.
